# What is the easiest way of removing the attribute of a node of an xml file in vb?

Tags: xml, vb6, msxml

I'm familiar with using the MSXML2 library for reading xml files. But is there an easy way of editing a particular node. Say I have the following line of code that selects a `dataroot` element that has the attribute `generated`:

```
Dim oDoc as MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim oNode as MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode    

Set oDoc = ... //open xml file here//
Set oNode = oDoc.selectSingleNode("/root/dataroot/[@generated]")
```

I want to be able to remove the `generated` attribute from the selected node and save the change back to the original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove an attribute from an node:

```
oNode.removeAttribute("generated");
```

To save the changes:

```
oDoc.save("changed.xml")
```

Comment: The removeAttribute method doesn't exist for me! I'm using MSXML v6.0. Any ideas?

Comment: Well its in the documentation.  Perhaps try @dunc's answer.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Just found out that the removeAttribute method is only available if oNode is declared as MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement and not MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Comment: Great, so change to `Dim oNode as MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement`.  You may have to cast the result of SelectSingleNode().  Sorry my VB is very basic.

Comment: @RichardSchneider I'm using vba actually and the casting is done automatically it seems.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the attribute from the Attributes collection of the node in question:

```
oNode.Attributes.removeNamedItem "generated"
```